# Error when specifying custom retry with the google cloud python lib

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm trying to create a subscriber with GCP PUB/SUB using the python sdk. According to the docs you can specify a `retry` arg on `create_subscription` to customise the retry delay as you would do in the UI via the web dashbaord. However when I do this I get the error

`Unknown field for Subscription: retry`

https://googleapis.dev/python/pubsub/latest/subscriber/api/client.html#google.cloud.pubsub_v1.subscriber.client.Client.create_subscription

```py
subscriber = pubsub.SubscriberClient()
    subscription_path = subscriber.subscription_path(env.GCP_PROJECT_ID, details['name'])
    push_config = pubsub.types.PushConfig(push_endpoint=details['endpoint'])

    custom_retry = retry.Retry(
        initial=60.0,
        maximum=600.0,
        multiplier=1.45,
    )

    # Wrap the subscriber in a 'with' block to automatically call close() to
    # close the underlying gRPC channel when done.
    with subscriber:

        subscription = subscriber.create_subscription(
            request={
                "name": subscription_path,
                "topic": topic_path,
                "push_config": push_config,
                "ack_deadline_seconds": 30,
                "retry": custom_retry
            }
        )
```

Comment: Maybe a library version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `retry` code you used is a generic code that may be used on some of the other google api's.

You may use `retry_policy` for the creation of subscription and can be used specifically for Pub/Sub. This will enable you to customize **Return Policy**-*Retry after exponential backoff delay* parameter which includes the **Minimum backoff** and **Maximum backoff**.

Please see below code and works for me when I compared the parameter specified in my code and the parameter specified on the created subscription using the GCP Pub/Sub user interface.

```
from google.cloud import pubsub_v1 as pubsub
from google.protobuf.duration_pb2 import Duration

subscriber = pubsub.SubscriberClient()
subscription_path = subscriber.subscription_path('<you_project>', '<your_subscription>')
push_config = pubsub.types.PushConfig(push_endpoint='<your_endpoint>')

#This is where you custom your Minimum Backoff and Maximum Backoff
minimum_backoff = Duration(seconds = 15, nanos = 0)
maximum_backoff = Duration(seconds = 550, nanos = 0)
retry_policy = pubsub.types.RetryPolicy(
      minimum_backoff=minimum_backoff,
      maximum_backoff=maximum_backoff
)

create_request=pubsub.types.Subscription(
    name=subscription_path,
    topic='projects/<your_project>/topics/<your_topic>',
    push_config=push_config,
    retry_policy=retry_policy
) 

with subscriber:

    subscription_resource = subscriber.create_subscription(
        request=create_request        
)
```

Comment: that's great thanks very much :)

Comment: We have configured retry policy at the pubsub subscriber level but still it is not retrying when we acknowledge the published message by error codes such as 400 or 500 .  We are expecting pubsub to resend the message in case of google api core exceptions such as resources exhausted or quota exceeded , please let me know if anything specific to be followed up to achieve that.